# Loading 3D Model but getting 2D Array in Python

Tags: python, numpy, slice, 3d-model

I`ve downloaded a sample .stl file from here: [https://www.thingiverse.com/thing:156207]

Then I've used this code to get a numpy array for further image processing with matplotlib:

```
import numpy as np
from stl import mesh
np.set_printoptions(threshold=np.nan)


# Using an existing stl file:
your_mesh = mesh.Mesh.from_file('300_polygon_sphere_100mm.stl')

data = np.array(your_mesh)
print(data.shape)
```

Unfortunately, this is an array with only two dimensions. I've checked the .stl file with my editor and there are three dimensions.

Can someone help me? My goal is to create a code with that i can slice 3D models to get acces to the sliced 2d images.

Thanks.

EDIT: I've tried to reshape it:

```
data_reshaped = np.reshape(data, (550, 3, 3))
```

But i guess this totally wrong. And i don't know if the pattern is (Z, X, Y).

I want to do some slicing operations on the 3d array to get XY images like this guy is very easily doing https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5jQVQE6yfio&list=PLT66ZlnovHPYzny9TYM1mx02k5Xnw_kjw&t=215s&index=3

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to just load the `.stl` file into a numpy array and perform slicing as shown in the video you linked. In the video, they load a model that is stored as a 3D numpy array.

However, the model you are trying to load consists of a polygonal mesh. This means you only have the coordinate values of the vertices. You can open the `.stl` file in a text editor to see its contents. (By converting the loaded mesh into a numpy array you just extract those coordinate values. You can actually compare the values in the numpy array and the text file, they are the same.) The resulting numpy array has shape `(550, 9)`. The first dimension is defined by the number of faces in the model (in this case, the model has 550 faces). As each face has three vertices, which have three coordinate values each, hence you have 9 numbers per face. So the third dimension is not lost. It's just stored in a different manner.

Simply reshaping the array won't create you a model of which you can get slices of, as shown in the video. To achieve this, you have to convert the meshed model into a rasterized one. You could do this by initializing an empty 3D array that contains the whole model and then determining for each pixel if it intersects with the geometry of the mesh you loaded.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your input. That seems much more difficult than i initially thought. Because of that video i thought it will be easy for me to take any 3d volumetric model store it as a 3d numpy array and do slicing operations along axis to retrieve layer images (2d numpy arrays). 

This should be only a minor feature of my program. Do you know any library or tool that creates layer images of a 3d volumetric model. if i get 2d images i can easily convert them into grey scaled 2d numpy arrays for further processing. In the end i only need 2d arrays